# Indexing Firebase nodes based on value of a child's child using firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Index a nodes based on value of a child's child using Firebase rules

Is it possible to use Firebase rules to index all the children of votes by the value of there vote_count so i can return the first 10 nodes of votes and they will have the highest vote_count.  In order to avoid time consuming query's.

The data is structured as follows.

```
   {
    "votes": {
        "LXlcgMyGG16N9HdR4HD":{
            "vote_count": 2,
            "uid1": true,
            "uid2": true
        }   
         "LXlix7BiJ3D9ZFd4sS5":{
            "vote_count": 3,
            "uid1": true,
            "uid2": true,
            "uid3": true
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not valid JSON: `"vote_count":{3}`. Is it `"vote_count": 3`?

Comment: Yes it is, i have edited my question

Comment: It's still not valid JSON, but close enough. See my answer below. For future questions, you can get the JSON by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this JSON:

```
{
  "votes": {
    "LXlcgMyGG16N9HdR4HD":{
        "vote_count":2,
        "uid": true,
        "uid2": true
    }   
     "LXlix7BiJ3D9ZFd4sS5":{
        "vote_count": 3,
        "uid": true,
        "uid2": true,
        "uid3": true
    }   
  }
}
```

You can get the nodes with the 10 highest vote counts with:

```
firebase.database().ref("votes").orderByChild("vote_count").limitToLast(10)
```

There are a few things to note however:

1. You'll still be downloading the UIDs of everyone who voted. If you don't display that information, downloading them is a waste of bandwidth that will get worse as you get more users. In that case, consider adding a second top-level node with just the `vote_counts`.
2. The results will be in ascending order. If you want to show the top 10, that means you'll typically need to reverse them client-side. Given that it's only 10 items, performance impact of that should be negligible.

Also see the [Firebase documentation on ordering and filtering results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).